# android: calling onCreate in class w/o view

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, oncreate

I'm wondering how I can call an onCreate in a class that has no View in android.
I'm creating a data-class for sharedpreferences, but sharedpreferences need to be called in the onCreate.
my Class would look a bit like this:

```
public class getData extends PreferenceActivity {

String username;
String password;
String auth_key;
String PREF_FILE = "prefs";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        //SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        username = settings.getString("username",null);
        password = settings.getString("password",null);
        auth_key = settings.getString("auth_key",null);
}

public String getSHA1(){
    return password;
}
public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}
public String getAuth_key(){
    return auth_key;
}
```

any tips are a great help and well appreciated

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are not required to be created in onCreate() (If I understood you correctly).

Instead, you just need a context in place where you need to get sharedprefs. This could be your Activity or Service or simply other class which would act as a wrapper around preferences and implement some interface like you've posted.

So if you want to create such a wrapper, maybe, more elegant solution instead of inheriting from Activity something which is not actually an activity would be to create a class with constructor taking Context.

Besides, this class can even be singleton which gets initialized with Context once on application startup. This can be done from one of the activities of app or you can benefit from ability not often used - to have an instance of android.app.Application.
Provide a class name for your Application in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.yourpackage.YourApp" >
```

After this create YourApp class in corresponding package by extending android.app.Application. This class may only contain needed code for initializing singleton preferences wrapper with a context like this:

```
public class YourApp extends Application {

    public void onCreate() {
        SharedPrefsWrapper.initialize(this);
    }
}
```